# 18.04: Ubuntu freezes when using Wifi

Tags: 18.04, wireless, freeze

I have a slight problem with Ubuntu which freezes when I start to use Wifi, Wifi works without worries, it's just slow, but it starts to freeze randomly from time to time

I did some research, but nothing seemed to work, do you have a solution to offer me please?

edit:

No i am not using Virtualization, i'm running Ubuntu in DualBoot
sudo

lshw|grep -A15 'network\|Wireless' output:

```
           *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
            logical name: enp59s0
            version: 1f
            serial: e4:b9:7a:eb:7f:e9
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
            resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:ed304000-ed304fff memory:ed300000-ed303fff
    *-pci:3

       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: Wireless-AC 9260
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
            logical name: wlp60s0
            version: 29
            serial: 48:f1:7f:db:39:d6
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-26-generic firmware=46.6bf1df06.0 ip=192.168.1.23 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
            resources: irq:18 memory:ed200000-ed203fff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
```

Comment: Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? What's the result of `sudo lshw|grep -A15 'network\|Wireless'` ? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question. Please do not use Add Comment.